# Hexadecimal (&#xA7;) to Char (§) in Java

Tags: java, hex

I have a huge xml file which contains a lot hexadecimal values ex:  `&#xA7;`, so how to convert these hexadecimal value in entire file to Char ex: § (`&#xA7;`) in java.

```
<md.first.line.cite>UT ST &#xA7;&#x2002;10-2-409</md.first.line.cite>
```

Comment: Please provide more context. Can you give an example of the file's content? What have you tried to far?

Comment: Pasted the example , just one tag from xml . And tried this FileUtils.readFileToString(file,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Comment: @phuclv ok , so is there way  to convert this in java?

Comment: I'm confused. I don't see *any* hexadecimals in your example...

Comment: Assuming there really are some, you probably need `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml()`

Comment: @g00se the OP made a terrible mistake by not formatting the post properly, so HTML character references are converted to characters instead

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you want to convert to `§`,  so this is one of way to conver hex to your desired character:

```
  System.out.println((char)0xA7);
```

Or

```
int hex=0xA7;
System.out.println((char)hex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with what `&#xA7;` and `&#x2002;` mean.  These are XML character references.  They represent the Unicode code-points `U+00A7` and `U+2002`.  (This is real XML syntax, not just some random nuisance escape sequence that needs to be dealt with.)

So, if you parse that XML with a conformant XML parser, the parser will *automatically* take care of translating the references to the corresponding Unicode code-points.  Your application *should not need to* do any translating.

This implies that you are NOT using a proper XML parser in your application.  Bad idea!  Doing your own XML parsing by string bashing or using regexes tends to give inflexible code and/or unreliable results when faced with "variant" XML.  So my main recommendation would be:

- Use a standard off-the-shelf XML parser.
- If your XML is non-compliant, consider using Jsoup or similar to extract information from the XML.

If you already deep down the rabbit hole of string bashing, etc, the best thing to do would be to extract the entire encoded XML text segment and convert it to a `String` using existing library code.  The standard Java SE class libraries don't provide this functionality, but you could use `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml()` from `org.apache.commons.text`.  (The version from `org.apache.commons.lang3` has been deprecated.)

Comment: I did try StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml() , the problem I faced is .. I had process lakhs of xml , then I have to save them to Postgres DB ... the unescapeXml() did convert &#xA7; to section sign but insertion to DB failed becuase &amps; converted to & ..that also I replaced -- using s.replaceAll("&", "&amp;")...but then problem came for "<" , which when I converted using replaceAll("<","&lt;");, entire xml format changed ... so I am not able to parse entire xml.